# How to make a div with rounded corners

Tags: html, rounded-corners

How do you make a div so that its border corners are rounded?

Answer (score 37):

Here it is:

```
<style type="text/css">
div.test
{
    width: 115px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
}
</style>
<div class="test">This is some text!</div>
```

Comment: It's best if you remember to use prefixes such as "moz" (for Mozilla) and "webkit" (for Safari and Chrome.) Maybe there are more that I don't know about.

Answer (score 15):

Use the [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) property. The higher the specified amount (typically in `px`), the more rounded your shape. Example:

```
myDiv { border-radius:30px;}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 10):

add this css:

```
border-top-right-radius:15px;
border-top-left-radius:15px;
border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
```

Answer (score 6):

With CSS add the code: `border-radius: 10px`.

I use 10px for example, but you can experiment with however amount of pixels you like.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to rely on pixels, you can always use %

`border-radius: 50%;`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `"border-radius"` css property like this:

```
div {
     border-radius:8px;
}
```